# Canvas Paint method is not working with JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've been trying to create two layered images within a JFrame using JLayeredPane however I'm not able to draw a shape using the paint() function within the Canvas class.
Here is what I wrote:

```
package com.baduk.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private ImageIcon icon;
    private JLabel back;
    private JLayeredPane layer;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3441156857004256039L;

    public Game() {
        
        //Background image with depth 0 
        icon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/scaraven/Downloads/baduk_board.png");
        back = new JLabel(icon);
        back.setBounds(0,0,icon.getIconWidth(),icon.getIconHeight());
        
        //Create JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BADUK");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(icon.getIconWidth()+5,icon.getIconHeight()+25));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        //Create JLayeredPane
        layer = new JLayeredPane();
        
        
        layer.add(back,new Integer(1));
        layer.add(this,new Integer(0));
        
        
        frame.setContentPane(layer);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

According to what I wrote, A Jframe should be generated with an image as the background and a black rectangle on top, however I only get the image. Does anyone know what is wrong with the code I wrote and what I need to change?

Comment: A Canvas is heavyweight;  Swing components are lightweight.  Instead of a canvas, use a JPanel, and override its `paintComponent` method instead of paint.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/.

Comment: I think you'll need to set the bounds of your custom layer. You should probably debug without the image icon for the background first, just to make sure you're not painting over the top.

Comment: The official JLayeredPane tutorial is alright. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html